# GET vs POST for fetching HTML page

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, postman

Am able to fetch html page properly using postman GET But getting error while fetching html page using POST using postman
Error details :
 404 Not Found404 Not Found

---

We have frontend code on html/JS and backend code on nodeJS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen for so many reasons. Check your imports, routes and request url.
Though it is not the way to get your html through POST method. Using GET method is the right way.

```
 const express = require("express");
 const router = express.Router();
     router.post("/", (req, res, next) => {
     res.render("index", { title: "Express" });
     console.log(req);
     });
 module.exports = router;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is good if fetch data using GET method only and if it is giving 404 Error then it means you might have not created any route with POST method. Same route with different method treat as different route like

1) GET http://example.com/fetch

2) POST http://example.com/fetch

are 2 different routes. You need to define each separately

Answer (score 0):

I believe that for *fetching* data, GET is the preferred method and POST should be used to update server-side resources, not to retrieve them. If POST is returning 404, You may not have a POST route configured, or POST access may be disabled by itself through your server's configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the "GET" method is used when requesting the an html page, for example all the browsers, uses "GET" for requesting the landing page of any url.

Post usually is used to send data and logging in.

Answer (score 0):

> You need to create a route for POST requests to get the HTML.

I'm assuming that you must be using some kinda framework router like express-router to route your pages. In your router code, you would be having something like

`app.get('/myHtmlPage', function(req, res) {
   // some code
 })`

so you're getting your page back for making GET requests. You need to create a similar route like 
`app.post('/myHtmlPage', function(req, res) {
  // some code
})`
to get the same page for POST requests.